# How to Run Few Specs [it blocks] on firefox browser and few specs [it blocks] on Chrome browser in protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Say I have one test case (one js file - say `Test.js`) with 10 specs [10 `it` blocks] in it. Now, the requirement is we need to execute first 8 `it` blocks in chrome browser and the remaining two `it` blocks should run in firefox.

In another way how to initialize a browser at `it` block level wherever required. Is there any method/process to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to approach it is this way

```
it("Chrome specific test", async () => {

    let capabilities = await browser.getCapabilities();
    let browserName = capabilities.map_.get('browserName');

    if (browserName === "chrome") {
        // your test goes here
    } else {
        console.log("Test case will be skipped")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is parameter 'restartBrowserBetweenTests' which allows us to start browser on every it block.

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  **restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,**

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
  }
};
```

You can also change browser name in beforeEach which execute before every it block.
Sample code:

```
 beforeEach(async function() {
      var config = await browser.getProcessedConfig();
      config.capabilities.browserName = 'firefox';

      browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

      todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

First, There is no way supported in protractor Jasmine/Mocha test framework to run 'it' block separately of single spec file.

Second, This is not good idea to run 8 tests cases on one browser and rest on other browser. The purpose of testing on multiple browser is to check the application compatibility on each browser. In order to achieve this goal we should run all spec files and it blocks on all browser.

If you still want to do the same then you will have to create two spec files. one contains 8 it blocks and second contains 2 it blocks. Since you have requirement of running on different browser then you will have to create two config files in order to run spec files separately if you want to avoid manual changes in config file.

Comment: Is there any way to initiate new browser at it block level like what ever the browser type I want